# Initialiazation error cause by Out Parameter in C# function

Tags: c#, initialization

I have the following code:

```
double dd;
Dictionary<string, double> dic = new Dictionary<string,double>();
bool notin = this.summedVars.TryGetValue(bacino, out dic);
if(notin == false)
    this.summedVars.Add(bacino,dic);
dic.TryGetValue(id, out dd);
dic[id] = dd + d;
```

When I run it I get the error:

> dic is set to a null reference

How do I initialize `summedVars` with a new `Dictionary` without adding values?

Comment: can you add the complete code? where is summedVars declared?

Comment: Is it this line that produces the error: dic.TryGetValue(id, out dd) - if the value you are looking for is not in the summedVars dictionary then this line is still called since you only use your notin variable to decide to Add. Since dic is an out parameter - there is no need to initialize it

Comment: class member , private dictionary<string,dictionary<string,double>>

Comment: Your variable `notin` should be named `contains`(the opposite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect TryGetValue is nulling your output parameter (dic). You need a safety net after that line

e.g.

```
dic = dic ?? new Dictionary<string,double>();
```

Your code would become:

```
                double dd;
                Dictionary<string, double> dic;
                bool notin = this.summedVars.TryGetValue(bacino, out dic);
                dic = dic ?? new Dictionary<string,double>();
                if(notin == false)
                    this.summedVars.Add(bacino,dic);
                dic.TryGetValue(id, out dd);
                dic[id] = dd + d;
```

Comment: This line `dic[id] = dd + d;` is also risky. You should consider wrapping it with `if (dic.ContainsKey(id)) { /* success code */ } else { /* failsafe code */ } `.